# Need help to make a responsive footer?

Tags: html, css

Is there a way for the footer to be positioned at the bottom no matter how much content is on the page and the content does not overlap with the footer?

Thank You for all your help

Comment: Yes, this is possible. However, what have you tried so far, and what issues are you facing?

Comment: Yes, there definitely is.

Comment: Use google with words "html footer bottom"

Answer (score 0):

A better idea can be utilizing a css framework like twitter-bootstrap. but if you want to achieve that with css only, something like this in your css file will give you what you need:

```
footer {
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    position: fixed;     
}
```

In order to make sure, any content and footer will not overlap you can either set a `padding-bottom` in your body:

```
body {
    padding-bottom: 60px;
}
```

or have a content div which you set its 'margin-bottom':

```
.content {
    margin-bottom: 60px;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/salisayedi/nxoaddLd/)

Comment: That only gets them half way. They need to also make sure, as they say, that the footer doesn't overlap any content. You'll likely need to set a height on the footer, and a corresponding padding on the body - alternatively, some JS might be in order.

Comment: @AliSeyedi Why did you use in the footer position:fixed, wouldn't it be better to use position:absolute?

Comment: @RobertoFlores Because a `fixed` positioned element will stay where it is when the page is scrolled. And `absolute` positioned elements will be relative to the first positioned parent. I thought `fixed` is more appropriate for you as you required it "to be positioned at the bottom no matter how much content is on the page".

Comment: @AliSeyedi I see. But the issue is the page can change meaning there will be time that content can be one line and I was wondering if the footer can remain in the bottom.

Comment: @RobertoFlores with `fixed` positioning, the footer should remain in the bottom.

Comment: @AliSeyedi Even if the content changes meaning, let say it covers the half page, it will still remain? The page changes depending on what the user enters. If the user fills up the full page, the footer should be in the bottom. Same thing when the content the user has enter only fills up half the page.

Comment: @RobertoFlores Yes. I provided jsfiddle so you can see.

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox might be a solution which is pretty flexible. The footer will always be at the bottom of the page unless there is too much content, then it will just be at the end of the page (thus no "overlapping").

```js
document.getElementById("expand").addEventListener("click", function() { document.getElementById("long").style.display = "block"; });
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-content: stretch;
  height: 100vh;
}
header, footer {
  flex-basis: auto;
  flex-grow: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #ccc;
}
div#content {
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding: 20px;
}
div#long {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <header>This is the header with auto-height.</header>
  <div id="content">Short Content. <span id="expand"><strong><u>Click here more content!</u></strong></span>
  <div id="long"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x1000"></div></div>
  <footer>This is the footer, and always at the bottom of the window unless there's too much content.</footer>
</div>
```